# No provider for PlatformLocation

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an Angular module. So When I run `ng build pagination` or `ng serve` I got no error. But in the browser I get:

> NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Location ->
>   PlatformLocation]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Location ->
>   PlatformLocation]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PlatformLocation!"

This is how I'm calling my module:

```
"angular-my-module": "file:../angular-my-module",
```

The module configuration inside my web-app

```
import { AngularMyModule } from 'angular-my-module/dist/pagination';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularMyModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppRootComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here, how I'm calling the component

```
<lib-pagination [data]="pagination"></lib-pagination>
```

Now, my module files

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PaginationComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  exports: [PaginationComponent]
})
export class AngularMyModule { }
```

The module component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-pagination',
  ...
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() public data: Pagination;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private paginationService: PaginationService) {

  }
```

Looking for this error, I coudn't find a solution, so what could I be missing?

```
angular: 8.2.4,
```

Comment: You didn't post any code about the component that's throwing the error: PlatformLocation. Also I looked it up, from the docs: *This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location.* The error that you get indicates that `PlatformLocation` is being injected somewhere and that Angular can't find a provider for it: I don't think you're supposed to inject it, so try to find where in your project you use it, and post that

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper, the error occurs when I call ```AngularMyModule```, adding it to ```@NgModule({ imports: ...```, So... I post the code that I believe that it's related. And I'm not using ```PlatformLocation``` directly, some another module it's calling, but I don't know who.

Comment: So, AngularMyModule is not your root module? I think you're supposed to use `RouterModule.forChild()` instead then. Maybe that's why you get a Location related error?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper, right! ```AngularMyModule``` it's not the root module. Changing to ```.forChild()``` brings the error: ```ERROR NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PaginationComponent -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PaginationComponent -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!"```

Comment: You're dealing with a bug or another under-the-hood issue that throws a cryptic error. Could you try to upload a minimal reproduction example? Otherwise you'll just have to hope someone who's had the same error passes by and answers this :p

Comment: You're most likely overlooking some detail in how you've set up your modules and routing. Try to find an Angular tutorial/guide that does what you're trying to achieve and see if they work, and adapt from there

Answer (score 0):

I believe to have found a solution.

In this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11883) the problem seems to be related, so I tried to setup `tsconfig.json` accordingly.

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

This was made in my web-app (AppModule), NOT in my module (AngularMyModule)

No more console errors.